# unable to set separate colors for Odd and even rows

Tags: angular, css, typescript, ngx-datatable

here what i am trying i am displaying a dynamically generated table using ngx-datatable but i am trying to display is for odd rows i want to display one color and on for even row i tried applying the  nth element &

```
body .datatable-body-row .datatable-row-even {
    background: orange;
}



body datatable-body-row .datatable-row-odd {
    background: aqua;
   } 



   .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row.datatable-row-even {
    background-color: red;
}
```

i tried all these to set row colors for odd or even rows but these styles are not applying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the class names directly as below should work:

```
.datatable-row-even {
    background-color: red;
}

.datatable-row-odd {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Its working for me: [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-jesefv?file=styles.scss)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be achieved in pure css without marking rows with additional classes

```
.datatable-row-wrapper:nth-child(2n){
    background-color: red;
}

.datatable-row-wrapper:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color: blue;
}
```